# Css Animation not working correct

Tags: css, css-animations

I have to elements and I want to **animate** them **seperatly**. Element one should play animation one and element two should play animation two.
But when I test it element one plays both animations and element two none.
*This is not happening if I start the animation of element two with a delay, but this is no solution...*

Here's element one:

```
#wrapper_splashscreen #logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    -webkit-animation: logoIntro 0.5s 1; }
@-webkit-keyframes logoIntro
{
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.4, 1.4);
    }
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

and here's element two:

```
   #wrapper_splashscreen #menu {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background: #151515;
        -webkit-animation-name: menuIntro 1s 1; }
    @-webkit-keyframes menuIntro
    {
        0%, 30% {
            bottom: -40px;
        }
        100% {
            bottom: 0px;
        }
    }
```

The logo (element one) is fadeing in and moving down and the menu (element two) is doing nothing.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could set up a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2):

In the second element you've an error:

```
-webkit-animation-name: menuIntro 1s 1;
```

It should be `-webkit-animation`.

I'm not sure what's the problem with the first element (please add a fiddle/demo), buy maybe setting a [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) will help

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the animation becomes buggy when you navigate to the animated element with an anchor. The browser navigates to the element while its moving and the animation gets broken.